# Find transformation reflection of $y=mx$ using $[T]_\beta=[Q]^{-1} [T]_\alpha [Q]$

Tags: linear-algebra

In $R^2$ let $L$ be the line $y=mx$ where $m \neq 0 $. Find  an expression for $T(x,y)$, where

**(a)** $T$ is the reflection of $R^2$ about $L$

Do have guide to solve this problem but having trouble following it.

---

Let $\beta = \{ e_1,e_2 \} 
            = \left \{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0  \end{pmatrix}
                                  ,\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1  \end{pmatrix}
                \right     \}$
and $\alpha = \{ (1.m),(-m,1) \}$

Our game plan is to find $[T]_\beta=Q^{-1}[T]_\alpha Q$

First we find $[T]_\alpha$

$$\begin{aligned}
 T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ m \end{bmatrix}  \right) 
   &= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ m \end{bmatrix} 
   = 1 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ m \end{pmatrix} + 0 \begin{pmatrix} -m \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\\  T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} -m \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}  \right) 
   &= \begin{bmatrix}m \\ -1 \end{bmatrix} 
   = 0 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ m \end{pmatrix} - 1 \begin{pmatrix} -m \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

So, $$\begin{bmatrix} 
       T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ m \end{bmatrix}  \right)
    \\  T\left ( \begin{bmatrix} -m \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}  \right)
    \end{bmatrix} 
     = \begin{bmatrix}
      1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1
     \end{bmatrix}
          \begin{bmatrix}
         \begin{pmatrix}
         1 \\ m
         \end{pmatrix}
         \\ \begin{pmatrix}
                  -m \\ 1
                  \end{pmatrix}
         \end{bmatrix}$$

making $$ [T]_\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

Calculating $[I_v]_\alpha ^\beta$
$$ \begin{aligned} 
I_v\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ m\end{pmatrix}   &= \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ m\end{pmatrix} =1*e_1+m*e_2
\\I_v\begin{pmatrix} -m \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}   &= \begin{pmatrix} -m \\ 1\end{pmatrix} =-m*e_1+1 *e_2
\end{aligned}
$$

So, $$ \begin{bmatrix}
I_v\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ m\end{pmatrix} 
\\I_v\begin{pmatrix} -m \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & m \\ -m& 1
\end{bmatrix}   \begin{bmatrix}
e_1 \\e_2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Making $$Q^{-1} = [I_v]^\beta_\alpha= \begin{pmatrix}
1 &-m\\ m & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

**but guide has that** $$Q^{-1} = [I_v]^\beta_\alpha= \begin{pmatrix}
1 &m\\ -m & -1
\end{pmatrix}$$

anyways, from that we can find $Q$ by rref$[Q^{-1}:I_V]= [I_V:Q]$
we should get that $$[T]_\beta= Q^{-1}[T]Q
                             = \begin{pmatrix} 
                               \frac{1}{m^2+1}  & \frac{m}{m^2+1} \\ \frac{m}{m^2+1} & \frac{m}{m^2+1} \end{pmatrix}$$

That is $$T(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix} 
                               \frac{1}{m^2+}  & \frac{m}{m^2+1} \\ \frac{m}{m^2+1} & \frac{m}{m^2+1}
                    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}
                               =-\left ( \frac{x+ym}{m^2+1} , \frac{xm+ym^2}{m^2+1}\right) $$

---

Appreciate constructive input thanks

---

**after ans, comments from amd, cannot get the answer because following the bold part gives out a diff answer than it should on CAS**

Comment: $T(-m,1)^T=(m,-1)^T$, not $(-m,1)$. You left out some minus signs there.

Comment: You have other errors, but I’m reluctant to edit your question because I can’t tell which ones are simple typos and which are actual errors in your calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help you to draw some pictures of what’s going on, such as this:

[image]

We pick a basis $\alpha$ in which the transformation matrix will have a particularly simple form. Any vector on the line is its own image, while by definition of reflection any vector orthogonal to it gets negated. So, if we choose a basis that consists of a vector on the line and a vector orthogonal to it, and remembering that the columns of a transformation matrix are the image of the basis, we can write $T_\alpha$ down immediately: $$T_\alpha=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}.$$ $(1,m)$ is a convenient choice for the vector on the line, which suggests $(-m,1)$ for the orthogonal vector since it’s just $(1,m)$ rotated 90°.

The rest is now a matter of finding the change-of-basis matrix and computing the resulting transformation matrix. Again, if you remember that the columns are the image of the basis, you can write the change-of-basis matrix down directly.